# Redirect file access

Tags: windows, ntfs

I need to redirect access to some files (the same way as WOW64 File System Redirector does). Is this possible? Any 3rd-part software to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the scenario, there are a variety of ways to do this.  The simplest way is to just create either a hardlink or a symlink to the file you need to redirect.  For example, I have an old program that stores all its ini files in the Program Files directory.  This pops the UAC prompt like crazy.  The solution was to move the ini files and leave hardlinks in the Program Files directory.